# how to add oracle oci libraries to C++ eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, oracle

I'm writing a  method for Oracle in C++.  I’m using the OCI library with Eclipse as my IDE. The code compiled completely but I’m getting this runtime error:

```
"error while loading shared libraries: libocci.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory "
```

I included occi and clntsh  and nnz11 through properties > c/c++ general /Path and symbols > libraries

I don't know how to fix this error, please help thanks you

Answer (score 1):

IDE wont take  like libocci.so.11.1
you have to convert into like libocci.so

ln -s libocci.so.11.1

then it will be renamed to libocci.so

then compile the code

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler finds the libraries because your project probably specifies where to look for libs (-L flag on the linker command line). But the runtime linker needs to find the libs as well.

I assume you're running it on linux. You have 2 options:

1. A temporary solution is to define in your environment LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`full path to dir where libocci.so* is installed`. I'm not very familiar with eclipse, but there's likely a setting to change the runtime environment. You could also set LD_LIBRARY_PATH and then run ecplise in that env.

   $ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...

   $ command to run eclipse
2. A permanent solution is to add the full path to the dir. where the libs are to the file /etc/ld.so.conf, or better: create a file /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle and put the path in that file, nothing else. Then, as root, run ldconfig.

Answer (score 0):

wow . finally i did it , by one variable and put it into .bashrc

1- export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient  "The Path of libraries" and then 
2- root@user:~# vi .bashrc                            "Make sure you are in root" 
3- LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient/         "Add this two lines into file"
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

:)